# Showing xdebug with firefox 29.0

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Since the latest update with firefox i can't seem to find  my Xdebug.

I have tried going to `Show`->`tools`

but they changed the way you add the developer line.

Has anyone experianced the same and know how to show  the bottom line where you enable / disable `xdebug`?

Comment: Seriously is no one using xDebug and firefox?

Comment: i know its not the same but did you try firebug with firephp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

With the last update it disappeared almost everything :-)

Now there is an add-on toolbar hidden by default.

If not over there you can search in the upper right corner where there is a button with the *tooltext* "Open Menu" (3 horizontal lines). When you press the button it appears a panel, if you select *customize* on the bottom it will open a page with *Additional tools and features*. I find over there some of the add-on that I installed.

---

Original:

Did you refer to the bar that appear with `Shift + F2` ?

Under Tools-->Web Developer there is the list of tools directly available.

with `Crtl + Shift + S` you enable the debugger
with `Ctrl + Shift + I` you toggle the tools panel

Comment: this is for debugging Javascript and not PHP (using Xdebug)

Comment: With the last update it disappeared almost everything :-) Now there is an `add-on toolbar` hidden by default. In the upper right corner there is a button with the tooltext "Open Menu". When you press the button appear a panel, if you select customize open a page with additional tools and features. I find some of the add-on that I installed over there.

Answer (score -1):

this is a working add on for xdebug -- firefox 29..
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug-with-moveable-/?src=api